# Visual studio for mac C# language version

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I am currently coding in C# for scripts to be used in Unity, using Visual Studio for Mac and it tells me that I cannot use "interpolated strings" (as it is not available in C# 4 only available in version 6 or higher). I have looked for options to change the language version but I have failed to find one. Please tell me if I have configured wrongly or any way to change the language ver. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this help? https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St

Comment: No that is for windows, I am using MAC.

Comment: To do the same in Visual Studio for Mac, first open a C# solution. 
In the Solution pane, right-click on the **project-level** folder, and select "Options." (Any other folders such as Solution or organizing folders _will not_ show the correct Build menu.)
Select General in the Build category to reveal "Language Options." There should be a "**C# Language Version**" drop-down option, that lets you compile to a different C# version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your scripting runtime language from ([Updated scripting runtime in Unity](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/28/updated-scripting-runtime-in-unity-2018-1-what-does-the-future-hold/))

> Edit->Project Settings->Player->Other Settings->Configuration->Scripting Runtime Version.

**[String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)** was introduced from version `c#6`, for lower versions you can use [`string.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which is basically the same, only it little bit longer to write. String Interpolation is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `string.Format()`.

For example:

```
int num = 10;
string str = $"Number: {num}";
```

is the same:

```
int num = 10;
string str = string.Format("Number: {0}", num);
```

Comment: hmm.. someone has to update the code colorization of SO to color interpolated strings right.

Comment: Thank you and sorrry for being blind, because I've been googling and people have been telling me to edit it in VS (but only in Windows)

Comment: This answer def doesn't seem like the best one. It is describing a Visual Studio for Mac that I don't have. The best answer is provided by David Tag in the question above. The menu described in this answer does not exist on visual studio mac.